# What's the preferred Pascal file extension?

Tags: file, pascal

Is it:

- `.p`
- `.pl`
- `.pas`
- `.pascal`

Or something else?

And will the various Pascal compilers (notably fpc) bork if you don't use the preferred extension?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The most common file extension for Pascal is `pas`. As for FPC, it uses the `pp` extension to denote *FPC-specific* code.

I think there is not a "preferred" extension, but you can't miss by using `pas`.

Comment: Originally, it was intended to use ".pp" for FPC specific code, so code that used FPC dialects. However this has all blurred a bit since Delphi has implemented many FPC "extensions" since. But .pas, .pp and .lpr and .dpr are fairly normal. The rest is just compatibility with old Pascal compilers (like Unix Pascal and Mac compilers that use ".p")

Comment: I never saw .pl or .pascal btw. At least not on normal systems

Comment: Note .pl could also be Perl, so probably .pl is best avoided for Pascal.

Answer (score 1):

`.pl` is a bad idea, because it will conflict with both perl and prolog programs.

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)) `.pp`, `.pas`, `.inc` are valid (last one for include files).

You may also check [FreePascal Wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/File_extensions), which describe `.pas` as

> Unit with Pascal code (typically for a form stored in a corresponding *.lfm file)

and `.pp` as

> Pascal code

I believe you should use one of these two depending of your own preferences.